# Radion button as image does not uncheck upon clicking other radio button

Tags: html, css

I want to simply uncheck radio button upon clicking the other one in the list. (that's how radio is supposed to work ?)

Here's my code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <label>Payment methods:</label>
        <input type="radio" name="pp" id="pp" checked>
        <label for="pp">
            <img src="../img/pp-icon.png">
            <div>Paypal</div>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <label style="visibility: hidden;">Payment methods:</label>
        <input type="radio" name="skrill" id="skrill">
        <label for="skrill">
            <img src="../img/skrill-icon.png">
            <div>Skrill</div>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
input[type=radio]{ /* HIDE RADIO */
    visibility: hidden; /* Makes input not-clickable */
    position: absolute; /* Remove input from document flow */
}
input[type=radio] + label>img{ /* IMAGE STYLES */
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 100px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.2s linear;
}
input[type=radio]:checked + label>img{ /* (RADIO CHECKED) IMAGE STYLES */
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}
```

PROBLEM DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/gsda8s6r/ (radio buttons not hidden)

Live photo:
[image]

Thanks for your help!

Comment: both `radio buttons` must have the same `name`, can't be different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The radio buttons must have same name, you can place the image inside the label tag
here is update fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/gsda8s6r/1/

```
<div class="col-sm-2">
        <label>
        <input type="radio" name="payment" id="pp" checked>
        <img style="max-height: 100px; width: auto;" src="http://www.aganis.it/siti-web-trento-blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/img-logo-paypal.png">
        <div>Paypal</div>
      </label>
    </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <label>
        <input type="radio" name="payment" id="skrill">
        <img style="max-height: 100px; width: auto;" src="https://content.skrill.com/fileadmin/content/images/business/global_coverage_icon.png">
        <div>Skrill</div>
        </label>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this fiddle: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kirtan3d/gsda8s6r/3/)
I have changed some of your CSS, but I think you'll get the trick.
As others told, name of the radio button should be same. And you need to hide your default radio buttons with the following CSS.

```
input[type=radio].custom {
  display: none;
}
```

Add "custom" class to your radio input tag.
That's it. This is a trick! ;-)